# How do I use the primitives no-patches no-links no-turtles?

Tags: netlogo

The NetLogo dictionary contains these entries with no examples:
no-patches no-links no-turtles

All the description says for them is "Reports an empty patch/link/turtle agentset."

Can someone provide examples of how they are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost never need them. Generally, they're so you can initialize an agentset that you'll be constructing over iteratively or over time.

For instance, suppose we have a file that lists a bunch of patch coordinates like so:

```
15 7
-3 18
11 -2
```

Suppose we want to get the corresponding patches. You could do something like:

```
file-open "my-patch-data.txt"
let specified-patches no-patches
while [ not file-at-end? ] [
  let x file-read
  let y file-read
  set specified-patches (patch-set (patch x y) specified-patches)
]
```

Most of the time, however, it's far easier to just use NetLogo's agentset querying primitives (like `with`, `of`, `n-of` and so forth) to construct agentsets, so you don't need this too much.

Edit: As Nicolas points out, it's actually faster to do this by constructing a list of patches and then converting it to an agentset like so:

```
file-open "my-patch-data.txt"
let specified-patch-list []
while [ not file-at-end? ] [
  let x file-read
  let y file-read
  set specified-patch-list lput (patch x y) specified-patch-list
]
let specified-patches patch-set specified-patch-list
```

I did think of another example though. Suppose each of your turtles needs to keep track of the turtles that they encounter as they move around. You could store this in a turtles-own variable as a turtle-set. You need to initialize the group of turtles somehow, though. That's what `no-turtles` is for.

Comment: And even in this case, it's faster to first build a _list_ of patches (or turtles or links) and _then_ convert it to an agentset with [`patch-set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-set) (or `turtle-set` or `link-set`).

Comment: Good point Nicolas. Couldn't come up with any other examples that I couldn't immediately think of a better way to do with agentset operations though.

Comment: +1 for initializing turtles-own turtle-sets. In flocking model, for example, the turtle-set `flockmates` is declared as own variable but is not initialized in setup as `no-turtles`. So measures like mean crowding (`mean [count flockmates + 1] of turtles`) fail when included in the plot (or calculated from headless simulations).

Comment: Sandpile (Sample Models -> Chemistry & Physics) has an example use of `no-patches`; Mouse Drag Multiple Example (Code Examples) has an example use of `no-turtles`. They're similar to what's already been described, though. I agree these are rarely used prims, but it does occasionally come up.

Comment: Very good point @bergant! I [updated](https://github.com/NetLogo/models/pull/165) the Flocking models. I will also add a note describing this as good practice in our [coding guidelines](https://github.com/NetLogo/models/wiki/Coding-Guidelines).